# Move button closer to the expand button

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

In Vuetify, if I want to move my delete button closer to the expand button.
How do I do that ?

```html
<v-expansion-panel-header>
  {{ vehicle.VIN }}
  <v-icon v-if="type == 'saved'" color="teal"> mdi-check </v-icon>
  <v-btn
    text
    v-if="type == 'saved'"
    color="red"
    @click="remove(index, type)"
  >
    DELETE
  </v-btn>
</v-expansion-panel-header>
```

[image]

Comment: Would you recommend using the row column to do this?

Comment: @NehaSoni Yes, I am open to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset the `flex-grow` property on the delete button using a Vuetify helper class.

```
class="flex-grow-0"
```

**Snippet**:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-expansion-panel-header>
      {{ vehicle.VIN }}
      <v-icon v-if="type == 'saved'" color="teal"> mdi-check </v-icon>
      <v-btn
        class="flex-grow-0"
        text
        v-if="type == 'saved'"
        color="red"
        @click="remove(index, type)"
      >
        DELETE
      </v-btn>
    </v-expansion-panel-header>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

**Vuetify Docs**: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/flex/#flex-grow-and-shrink

Comment: Work perfectly, I didn't know about this build in class, thank-you.

Comment: Nice one @code-8, please mark answer as excepted?

Comment: If I remove the checkmark, having only delete button, that class doesn't work. What class should I use instead ?

Comment: Add a <v-spacer> component instead https://codepen.io/alexpetergill/pen/ZERmJyz/0e8949a58f59a246841ef472516e8bc6

Comment: Its a  solution, but <v-spacer> does not work sometimes. Its results are uncertain based on the width of the parent.

Answer (score 1):

It can also be achieved using row and column-

```
<v-expansion-panel-header>
    <v-row no-gutters>
        <v-col>
            hello
        </v-col>
        <v-col>
            <v-icon color="teal"> mdi-check </v-icon>
        </v-col>
        <v-col align="right">
            <v-btn text color="red">
                DELETE
            </v-btn>
        </v-col>
    </v-row>
 </v-expansion-panel-header>
```

Comment: Thanks @Neha let me try. 